# Consolidate console application into single binary

Tags: c#, console-application, exe, windows-console

I've been writing console apps for a couple months now. But each "app" comes with several files. The two that are needed are the exe and the config file. Is there a way to package both those files into a single exe?

I recognize I may loose the ability to edit the settings of the console application without a recompile.

Is it possible to maintain the ability to edit the settings with in the new binary? The console app must retain the ability to pass arguments at run-time.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging .NET application with its configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836280/merging-net-application-with-its-configuration)

Comment: What's the motivation for merging into a single file?